# Php how to extract the recursive list from html in php using dom?

Tags: php, dom, xpath

here is the following recursive list in HTML

```
<ul>
<li>
     <ul>
     <li>Sub-Item 1</li>
     <li>Sub-Item 2</li>
     </ul>
</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

I wanted to extract the first and the third list element of the main ul.

here is the code

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

// to get first list item of main ul <ul><li>Sub-Item 1<li>
 //    <li>Sub-Item 2<li></ul>
$nav =$xpath->query('//li[1]');
echo $nav->item(0)->nodeValue;

//to get second list itrm of main ul <li>Item 3</li>
$nav =$xpath->query('//li[3]');
echo $nav->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

but I am getting this as output

```
   <li>Sub-Item 1<li>
    <li>Sub-Item 2<li>

    <li>Sub-Item 3<li>
```

it's considering the sublist in the second XPath query.. can someone tell me what's the correct query. I am new to dom thing.

Edit: the main target is to save it as PHP array as shown below

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Sub-Item 1
            [1] => Sub-Item 2
        )

    [1] => Item 2
    [2] => Item 3
)
```

Comment: First of all, change `<li>` at the end of strings to close tag `</li>` -  `<li>Sub-Item 1</li>`. And in the next line

Comment: ignore that it was a typo I wrote it manually for the simplicity of html... corrected

Answer (score 0):

$rez =$xpath->query('(//ul/li)[1]');//for first

$rez =$xpath->query('(//ul/li)[last()]'); //for last

Comment: good try ..thanks for the answer but I need a general approach where there will be many li elements and many recursive li and wanted to get and store them in an array

Comment: Could you give an example of output? Do you need only first and third elements of main ul?

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Sub-Item 1
            [1] => Sub-Item 2
        )

    [1] => Item 2
    [2] => Item 3
)

Answer (score 0):

Xpath does not rearrange the nodes, so a nested structure is not possible. The return value is a list of nodes, they keep their position in the document (parent, children, ...). To create the recursive array structure you will need some more PHP logic:

```
function readListElement(\DOMElement $li) {
    // get an xpath instance
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($li->ownerDocument);
    // check if the node has an ul child
    if ($xpath->evaluate('count(ul) = 0', $li)) {
        // if not return the text inside
        return $li->textContent;
    }
    // otherwise 
    $result = [];
    // iterate the inner ul li elements
    foreach ($xpath->evaluate('ul/li', $li) as $liChild) {
        // and call the function itself
        $result[] = readListElement($liChild);
    }
    return $result;
}

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

// get the top level ul (has no ul ancestor)
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//ul[not(ancestor::ul)]') as $ul) {
    $result = [];
    foreach ($xpath->evaluate('li', $ul) as $li) {
      $result[] = readListElement($li);
    }
    var_dump($result);
}
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "Sub-Item 1"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "Sub-Item 2" 
  } 
  [1]=> 
  string(6) "Item 2" 
  [2]=> 
  string(6) "Item 3" 
}
```